# Groovy AST transformation - How to compile java annotated class with Gradle and Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to develop a Groovy AST transformation to add some methods on certain classes. So I write an annotation class and corresponding transformation class. Then I annotate a java class with my Groovy AST annotation.

When I compile the java annotated class with embedded groovy compiler (for example by this snippet: `Class enhancedClass = new GroovyClassLoader().parseClass(new File("..."));`), the transformation is performed and methods are added to the compiled class which  is called `enhancedClass` in the snippet.

But I cann't compile the java class with Gradle groovy plugin and Intellij IDEA correctly.

**QUESTION:** Can everyone help me to working with Groovy AST transformation in Gradle and Intellij IDEA?

**NOTE 1:** I use Intellij IDEA 14 ultimate edition.

**NOTE 2:**
My Groovy AST classes and the java annotated class and my "build.gradle" file are somethings like the followings:

Annotation class:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@GroovyASTTransformationClass(classes = {MyASTTransformation.class})
public @interface MyAST {
}
```

and Transformation class:

```
@CompileStatic
@GroovyASTTransformation(phase = CompilePhase.SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS)
public class MyASTTransformation implements ASTTransformation {
   @Override
   public void visit(ASTNode[] nodes, SourceUnit sourceUnit) {
      ...
   }
}
```

The java annotated class:

```
@MyAST
public class A {
   ...
}
```

The "build.gradle" file:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
sourceSets {
    main {
       groovy {
          srcDirs = ['src/main/groovy', 'src/main/java']
       }
        java {
          srcDirs = []
      }
   }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.4'
}
```

Comment: is `@MyAst` Supposed to have the est quote on the end?

Comment: Do not place the 'src/main/java' in the groovy sourceSet. In fact, you don't need either, as the default for groovy is 'src/main/groovy' anyway. And remove the `srcDirs=[]` from the java sourceSet.

Comment: Quote on the end of `@MyAST` was typing wrong and removed.

Comment: Mentioned modifications also don't solve the problem.

Comment: Are you trying to use the transformation in the same project that you are defining it? If so, that will not work unless you use the GroovyShell. Generally you want your AST in a separate project from the classes that will use it.

Comment: I separate projects but doesn't solve the problem. I think that AST compiled classes must be added to groovy compiler classpath. How can I do it? I was add a line that looks like `compile project(':ast')` to "build.gradle" file in separated project. Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

I created my first custom AST transformation and I also ran into similar issues so sharing my limited experience. I'm using Groovy 2.4.7 and IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.2. I was only able to use the custom transform annotation if:

1. It was created as a separate artifact (project) and another project that was using the annotation referenced it.
2. Ran a Groovy test script in the same project as the custom AST transformation code that ran a GroovyShell with Groovy code that used the custom annotation.

I had first attempted doing it in the same project but that didn't work. I believe it's because the AST transformation occurs at compile time. Here's my example:

---

**AST transformation project**

Annotation

```
@Retention (RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target ([ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD])
@GroovyASTTransformationClass (classes = [SqlAssistTransform])
@interface SqlAssist {
}
```

Transformation

```
@GroovyASTTransformation(phase=CompilePhase.SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS)
class SqlAssistTransform extends AbstractASTTransformation {
...
}
```

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'groovy-sql-transform'
```

build.gradle

```
...
group = 'com.company.groovy.transform'
version = '1.0-groovy-2.4'
description = 'Groovy AST transformation for SQL syntax'
...
```

---

**Project using AST annotation**

Annotated class

```
@SqlAssist
class Something {
...
}
```

Dependency example #1 - dependency on AST artifact from repository

> build.gradle
>
> ```
> ...
> dependencies {
>      ...
>     // As long as your local repository (or remote repository) has the AST transformation project installed. i.e. Run '.\gradlew install' in AST project to install to local repository
>     compile group:'com.company.groovy.transform', name:'groovy-sql-transform', version: '1.0.0-groovy-2-4'
>     ...
> }
> ...
> ```

Dependency example #2 - dependency on AST project

> build.gradle
>
> ```
> ...
> dependencies {
>     ...
>     compile project(':groovy-sql-transform')
>     ...
> }
> ...
> ```
>
> settings.gradle
>
> ```
> rootProject.name = 'project-name'
>
> // Assumption that AST project lives at the same level as this project
> include "groovy-sql-transform"
> project(":groovy-sql-transform").projectDir = new File("../groovy-sql-transform")
> ```

---

**Testing**

I didn't create a proper unit test, but I did use the following to test and debugged in IntelliJ so I could look at the AST in different places in my AST transformation code. Example test Groovy script that I had within the AST transformation project:

```
new GroovyShell(getClass().classLoader).evaluate '''

import com.company.groovy.transform.SqlAssist

@SqlAssist
class Testing {
...
}

'''
```